# Integrals given by Landau

Tags: soft-question, mathematics, history, integration

Discussion about Landau's "Theoretical Minimum" has already been posted [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13861/lev-landaus-theoretical-minimum). Unfortunately I couldn't find much about some examples of questions he gave to students. There are three questions in the post I linked and also in the linked arXiv [article](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0204295v1).

What I am mostly interested in are math exercises.

There is a history of Alexei Abrikosov who after presenting himself as a 3rd year student to Landau was asked if he had a pen and then was given an integral to solve. He managed to solve it and Landau was very happy :).

There are many other such anecdotes but they all lack exercise formulation. Maybe you know what this integral could be or at least of what type it was?