# On solving Lev Landau's theoretical minimum exam question

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, probability

I'm trying to answer the following question which was asked in the theoretical minimum exam composed by Lev Landau.

> The electron enters a straight pipe of circular cross section (radius $r$). The tube is bent at a radius $R\gg r$ by the angle $\alpha$ and then is aligned back again. Find the probability that the electron will jump out.

**Here is my attempt:**

As mentioned in the question, the tube is bent and assuming that this action takes place after the electron's entry, the tube would oscillate with a specific frequency after its release, this frequency would depend upon properties of the tube and it's gravitational potential. The depression of the loaded end is 
[image]
$$\xi=\frac{Mg}{YI}\left(\frac{l^3}{3}\right)$$, hence the restoring force is proportional to the depression. The frequency of oscillations is hence,$$f=\frac{1}{2\pi}\left(\frac{3YI}{Ml^3}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
With this being said how can I construct a potential that oscillates with such a frequency? I ask this because if there is an oscillating potential barrier for the electron, which(the potential) has its peaks higher than the electron's Energy and allows transversal motion of the electron only when the potential reaches a minima;hence making the electron move in small steps. Below I have written down the strain and gravitational potential energies and used them in the Schrödinger equation as the associated wavefunction gives the probability of finding a particle at a certain position.

The potential strain energy of a bending tube is:
$$V_{b}=\frac{M\alpha}{2}$$
Since, $\alpha$ is related to the moment as:$\alpha=\frac{ML}{2YI}$, where $Y$ is the Young's modulus and I is the moment of inertia($I=\frac{Mr^2}{2}$), we can rewrite the potential equation as:
$$\boxed{V_{b}=\frac{RM\alpha}{Yr^2}}$$
Now since there is also a gravitational potential associated with the bent tube, it can be written as follows:
$$\boxed{V_{g}=\frac{2GM\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}{R\alpha}}$$

I now introduce [toroidal coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toroidal_coordinates),where $\tau=\ln\frac{d_{1}}{d_{2}}$(please refer to the wiki link), here since $d_{1}=d_{2}$, $x=y=0$, and $$z=\frac{a\sin\alpha}{1-\cos\alpha}=\frac{R^{2}\sin(\alpha)\left(1-\frac{r^{2}}{R^{2}}\right)}{\left(4R^{2}+4\frac{r^{4}}{R^{2}}-8\frac{r^{2}}{R^{2}}-1\right)}$$
Where $a=R^{2}-r^{2}$ and $\cos\alpha=-\frac{\left(4a^2-2R^{2}\right)}{R^{2}}$

> [image]

Now these potentials can be incorporated into the Schrödinger time independent as the associated wavefunction gives the probability of finding the particle at a certain position:
$$\boxed{\frac{\mathrm d^{2}\psi}{\mathrm dz^{2}}=-~\frac{2m}{\hbar^{2}}\left(E-\frac{RM\alpha}{Yr^2}-\frac{2GM\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}{R\alpha}\right)\psi(z)}$$

As observed from the above equation the gravitational potential energy oscillates sinusoidally, but how am I to construct a potential with the frequency I mentioned above. Am I right to assume the above potentials for solving this problem? If yes, how do I proceed further? Any help is appreciated.

**edit:** I have proceeded to answer by the above method as nothing is explicitly mentioned in the question as of how to go about solving it. I got this question from [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13861/lev-landaus-theoretical-minimum). I would also like to add that the above method I have used may be one where I am just complicating a simple problem, I may be wrong but not the question, I beg to differ as I believe that such a problem asked by Landau would not have a simple solution given that only 45 students ever passed the theoretical minimum.

Comment: Are you sure this is what the question means? (It's not at all clear, by the way.) I think you just have a tube of a given shape and have to calculate a scattering amplitude using a hard wall potential. I don't think strain or gravity are involved. But again, the statement of the question is hard to understand.

Comment: @Javier I got the question from here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13861/lev-landaus-theoretical-minimum. And why cant I solve it by my method, nothing about not using the properties of the tide is mentioned.

Comment: -1. I think this question is not useful. The problem is badly posed. What assumptions are you making? Why do you think it is necessary to use Schrodinger's equation? Why can't this be solved using Classical Mechanics? You (and Landau) seem to be making a simple problem far more difficult than it actually is. ... Moreover, **you are not asking about a conceptual difficulty**, as the homework-and-exercises policy requires. You  have not identified what the conceptual issues are in solving this problem.

Comment: @sammygerbil I just asked a question which I felt was difficult. I am still a student and no expert to judge the question's correctness and would certainly not question landau's problem. Why can't it be solved by Classical Mechanics? It could be done maybe but what I have written above is **my attempt to solution ** and not the solution, hence I asked the question. I respect your opinion, please do refer to the source I have got the problem from in the link: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13861/

Comment: I appreciate that you are trying to solve a 'difficult' problem. I am aware of your link. The purpose of this site is to enhance conceptual understanding - not to generate and solve complicated equations (which is mathematics) but to explain the physics behind the problem, so that the question is useful to other users. You have not explained your approach. Why do you think this is a QM problem? What is keeping the electron in the tube? Why do you think gravity is involved? You appear to be using whatever ideas you can think of instead of identifying what is going on here.

Comment: @sammygerbil Sure I will address these questions and make an edit. Thanks!

Comment: Looking for a difficult solution just because the problem was set on a notoriously difficult exam is not sensible. Maybe few of the 'genius' candidates solved it because they were too proud to give the obvious answer (the electron will always come out, eventually, because there's nothing confining it), which Landau might have given full marks for.

Comment: In your revised solution the tube is released and oscillates. But in the problem statement after being bent the tube **is aligned back again**. Maybe there is something *lost in translation* here, but these conditions do not seem to be the same.

Comment: The fact that this question was closed, a question given in one of the hardest physics exams there was, is nothing less than shameful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what it's worth, at [some obscure Russian forum](http://dxdy.ru/topic87579.html), I found some seemingly reasonable comments on this problem. According to these comments, one needs to calculate the minimum energy state of the electron in the straight pipe with energy $U_1$ and the minimum energy state of the electron in the circular bend pipe with energy $U_2$, which differs from $U_1$ (for some velocity of the electron, I guess), and then solve one-dimensional Schroedinger equation to obtain the probability of reflection (transmission) of the electron scattering on the potential barrier with height (or depth) $U_1-U_2$ and length $R \alpha$.